# What percent of computers in a software development company is a Mac computer?

Tags: software-industry, software-development

I am looking to buy some computers for my startup company. I see Mac computers are 2 or 3 times more expensive than Windows computers with the same specs. So I am interested to know if is it a matter/concern for developers who I will hire that if our computers are Mac or Windows machines?

We look using Flutter/Dart, NodeJS and some other web/mobile application technologies.

EDIT: My point in this question was to know if doing a task is possible with either of Mac/Windows/Linux machines (consider NodeJS programming for example), does it really a matter what is the type of the machine? (My question is more about the budget concerns).

I also don't have developers at the moment and just doing a rough estimation of the future costs.

Comment: Have you asked your developers? Some things will be easier to do on one platform. Some tools may only be available on one platform. Given you mention mobile, iOS development requires a Mac. Only your devs will be able to actually tell you if you _need_ one or the other, or if you have a choice.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's more about statistics than the workplace.

Comment: "I see Mac computers are 2 or 3 times more expensive than Windows computers with the same specs" - I wonder where you can buy a Windows M1 laptop.

Comment: I use both, but prefer mac as they last longer. But yhat is also my choice, having used pc, mac, sun and sgi machines...

Comment: I thought developers all prefer linux?

Comment: If you're making iOS apps (even with Flutter) then I recommend Mac. A Mac works very well for both platforms. You will need at least 1 if you want to build and view iOS output. With Windows only, your developers will only see the Android output... I've had experience working with a start-up using Flutter, and the devs on Windows eventually had to move to Mac because without they weren't able to fix Mac specific issues.

Comment: i've never known a professional developer that doesn't have both on their desk.  (I mean, would you want to "not make money" for a job which calls for one or the other, or x-platform jobs?)  anyone who does multiplayer stuff has a row of four or 5 assorted machines.  and of course you need specific machines for specific jobs, like mac for app store crap and nVidia for cuda etc

Comment: recall too that if this is app related, you will need a vast array of both iphones and droids

Comment: Don't buy computers in advance. The more you delay this decision, the better and cheaper they'll get. For instance, don't buy the older macs. Their prices still haven't come down yet (which makes no sense) and yet they're vastly inferior to the new ones with the M1 chip. Ask the developers you hire what they'll need, the overwhelming majority of them will want a Mac. Developers are horribly expensive. Asking them to switch platforms when they're already used to another platform is only going to annoy the hell out of them and such a decision may even impact their decision to join your company.

Answer (score 8):

> So I am interested to know if is it a matter/concern for developers who I will hire that if our computers are Mac or Windows machines?

Yes, it is. There are technical limitations to what each machine can do. Please consult your technical staff, developers mainly, what they prefer. Their preference will be driven by their role in your company. Frontend developers may prefer Macs, backend developers windows machines. if your backend is running on Linux, maybe the developers prefer Linux. If you build and deploy for mobile devices, if you target iOS devices, some people will need a Mac.

We cannot answer with specifics, but specifics are important. Buying either one or the other exclusively will be wrong and bring technical difficulties up to making certain tasks impossible.

So ask your developers what they *need*. They will know.

Comment: Also ask them what they _want_. You can't pay me enough to work with a crap computer all day.